# Docker for Windows unable to mount nfs drive with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

permission denied errors when attempting to mount an nfs drive to a docker container using a docker-compose file.

This error only applies when running Docker for Windows. I am able to successfully mount the drive on an Ubuntu host.

docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
   builder:
     image: some_image
     ports:
     - "8888:8080"
     volumes:
     - "nfsmountCC:</container/path>"

 volumes:
   nfsmountCC:
     driver: local
     driver_opts:
       type: nfs
       o: addr=<nfs_IP_Address>
       device: ":</nfs/server/dir/path>"
```

Docker for Windows Produces

```
ERROR: for test_1  Cannot start service builder: b"error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/test-master_nfsmountCC/_data': error while mounting volume with options: type='nfs' device=':</nfs/server/dir/path>' o='addr=<nfs_IP_Address>': permission denied"
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you enable the NFS features of windows ( run `DISM /online /get-features /format:table | findstr NFS` in the command prompt and check if everything is enabled) ? Are you able to mount the NFS manually with `net use Z: <ip_address>:</path/to/shared/dir/>` ?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 mounting a NFS volume from an Ubuntu server:

**NFS Server side:**

- allow the *nfs* and *mountd* services on your firewall (if you have one) on the NFS server
- add the *insecure* option in each relevant entry of your '/etc/exports' file

**Docker client side:** add the *hard* and *nolock* options to the NFS volume definition

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  builder:
    image: some_image
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    volumes:
      - "nfsmountCC:</container/path>"

volumes:
  nfsmountCC:
   driver: local
   driver_opts:
     type: nfs
     o: "addr=<nfs_IP_Address>,rw,hard,nolock"
     device: ":</nfs/server/dir/path>"
```